# How to solve "can't create Multiple Sparkcontext error "?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files.
I have a file in which I am creating  sparkcontext.

### create_spark.py

The code is like this

```
spark_conf = (SparkConf().setAppName(app_name)
                              .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                              .set("spark.task.maxFailures", "14")
                              .set("spark.port.maxRetries", "50")
                              .set("spark.yarn.max.executor.failures", "14"))



spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
sqlContext=HiveContext(spark_context)
```

Then there is another file which contains all the codes . name it : `function_file.py`

it has to functions namely: This function just does some operation with data.

```
def adjust_name(line):
    if line is not None:
        if "(" in line:
            if "\(" in line:
                tem1 = line.split("\(")
                return tem1[0]
            else:
                tem1 = line.split("(")
                return tem1[0]
        else:
            return line
    else:
        return line
```

Now we are creating udf of the `adjust_name` function as .

```
adjust=udf(adjust_name,StringType())
```

and we are using this udf in process_sql functions as

**and another function that does all the table loading and all . for exampl**e

```
def process_sql(sqlContext,source_db,processing_db,table_name):
    .
    .
    .df3 = df3.withColumn('org_name',trim(adjust(df3['col_name'])))
    return table_name.
```

and now in create_spark.py file I am importing function_file as a module.
and I am calling the process_sql function as

```
x= function_file.process_sql(sqlContext,source_db,processing_db,table_name)
```

all the arguments are defined in advance.
But I am getting error like :

> ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext() created by udf at function_file.py

### NOTE: I am restricted to use spark 1.6 only

#### EDIT : I got a clue , the UDF is creating sparkcontext even before my create_spark.py file is creating .

`:Connecting to Spark and creating context with dim_emp_atsc_test_4_sept spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)`
 `ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=process_handler.py, master=yarn-client) created by udf at ..`

Comment: try to post a small amount code that demonstrates the error. i suspect that you are pulling in the `create_spark.py` dependency from within your UDFs when you shouldn't be. this should have once on your driver only

Comment: @Brad I am really sorry but I am not sure which part is actually throwing error . If you can tell my in little detail ,  I may get the idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `HiveContext` and `SparkContext`.

Try to use just one of them or while creating `HiveContext` pass `SparkContext` as a constructor argument.

Comment: I have written wrong upside . Actually sparkcontext is pass only to the hivecontext   .

Comment: Even when i removed he Hivecontect part , it still gives the same error

Comment: ok, then the reason is different. Two questions: anywhere else SparkContext created? Can you add print before SparkContext creation and check how many times that code was invoked!

Comment: .No the sparkcontext is not created anywhere else .

Comment: I got a clue , the UDF is creating sparkcontext even before my create_spark.py file is creating .
`:Connecting to Spark and creating context with dim_emp_atsc_test_4_sept
 spark_context = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)`
 
`ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=process_handler.py, master=yarn-client) created by udf at ..`